# How to set a key on a component with React.cloneElement or React.Children.map

Tags: reactjs

I have a table parent component where I a map through data and set rows. I have created a component that should be used for each row. I am sending that to the table component as a child prop. This is the code in the table component:

```
     <TableBody>    
      {stableSort(data, getSorting(order, orderBy))
        .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
        .map(n => {
          const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
          return React.cloneElement(children, { eksamensett: n, isSelected,  handleClick: (event, id) => this.handleClick(event, id)});
        })}
      {emptyRows > 0 && (
        <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
          <TableCell colSpan={6} />
        </TableRow>
      )}
    </TableBody>
```

And this is the child component that I am cloning:

```
const EksamenssettRow = ({eksamensett, isSelected, handleClick, onEksamenssetClicked}) => (
  <TableRow
    hover
    onClick={() => onEksamenssetClicked(eksamensett)}
    role="checkbox"
    aria-checked={isSelected}
    tabIndex={-1}
    key={eksamensett.id}
    selected={isSelected}
  >
    <TableCell padding="checkbox" onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, eksamensett.id)}>
      <Checkbox checked={isSelected}/>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
      {eksamensett.id}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
      {eksamensett.klasse.klassekode}
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{eksamensett.navn}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{eksamensett.fastRekkefolge ? 'Fast eksamensset' : 'Randomisert'}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{formatStringToLocalDate(eksamensett.opprettetDatoTid)}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{getElapsedTime(eksamensett.endretDatoTid)}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
);
```

Then I get the warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Because this is what is being rendered in the react tree:

```
<EksamenssettRow>
  <TableRow key="1">
  <TableRow/>
<EksamenssettRow/>
<EksamenssettRow>
  <TableRow key="2">
  <TableRow/>
<EksamenssettRow/>
<EksamenssettRow>
  <TableRow key="3">
  <TableRow/>
<EksamenssettRow/>
```

How can I set the key to the component itself so that I can avoid this warning, which also causes my tests to fail?
I have also used `React.Children.map` instead of directly using a child:

```
return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
                      return React.cloneElement(child, { eksamensett: n, isSelected,  handleClick: (event, id) => this.handleClick(event, id)})
                    })[0]
```

That has given a `key` to `EksamenssettRow`, but every `EksamenssettRow` has received the same `key='.0'` How can I fix this?

Comment: if you pass a key to the child, there is no need to pass key into the cloneElement. are you looping through EksamenssettRow or TableRow? because EksamenssettRow has no key defined. is the array EksamenssettRow list?

Comment: also you should use React.Children.map if possible

Comment: I am looping in TableBody where I clone EksamenssettRow which renders TableRow, and I setting key to the TableRow, but I can't set they key to EksamenssettRow itself. So map function is creating a lot of EksamenssettRows that don't have keys.

Comment: EksamenssettRow has no key. I think if you use React.Children.map you won't need a key

Comment: I still get the same error, React.Children.map creates the same key in this case, every  EksamenssettRow has received a key .0

Comment: I use it in my code like this
 {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
                React.cloneElement(child, {
                  onClick: this.changeTab,
                  tabIndex: index,
                  isActive: this.isActiveIndex(index)
                })
              )}

with no key, also the children have no key.
So its weird to me that it doesnt work

Comment: created a small fiddle for example. no React.Children.map even https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cloneelement-07b0z

Comment: I got it working eventually, not sure what went wrong the first time, but now when I am sending key with other props it works

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set a second parameter in map to index, then give the highest level JSX elment a prop `key={index}`

Comment: I know that, but where does the key go in a cloneElement, first parameter is the element, second props, where does the key come?

Comment: do you have a repo i can get on my machine so i can solve bug?